Monthly compounding interest with monthly contributions calculation does not return the correct values
My code is supposed to calculate the yearly balance using compounding monthly interest with contributions, but it returns values that are the incorrect amount. As an example, if initial investment is 1869.57, monthly deposit is 14, interest rate is 9.50, and the term is 19 years, then it's supposed to return 20193.81; instead it returns 20264.33. How would I fix it so it returns the correct values?
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

double balanceWithMonthlyDeposit(double initialInvestment, double monthlyDeposit,
                                 double interestRate, int numberOfYears)
{
    double interestEarned;
    double previousBalance = initialInvestment;  // Principal
    double interest = (interestRate / 100.0) / 12.0;  // Convert interest rate to decimal


    for (int i = 0;  i < numberOfYears;  ++i) { // For each year
        double yearlyInterest = 0;
        for (int j = 0;  j < 12;  ++j) { // For each month
            interestEarned = previousBalance + monthlyDeposit;
            interestEarned = interestEarned * interest;
            yearlyInterest = yearlyInterest + interestEarned;
            previousBalance = previousBalance + monthlyDeposit + interestEarned;


        }

        std::cout << "Year " << i + 1 << ": earning "
                  << interestEarned << "/month; "
                  << "(total=" << yearlyInterest << "); "
                  << "balance now " << previousBalance
                  << '\n';
    }

    return previousBalance;
    // return the ending balance
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2);
    double balance = balanceWithMonthlyDeposit(1869.57, 14, 9.50, 19);
    std::cout << "Final result = " << balance << '\n';
}

I've tried implementing a formula that I found online but it didn't work as intended.

You can't just take an interest rate, divide it by 12, and then take it to the 12th power. That's not how this works. I wish, though.

@user207421, it's completely wrong.  You need the twelfth root of the multiplier - in this case, std::pow(1 + rate/100.0,  1.0/12).  One twelfth is a reasonable approximation but not appropriate for exact calculation.  Subtract 1.0 to get back to the unit of the interest variable here, of course.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a main() function and at least one #include. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem (including any necessary inputs, but preferably not needing any), then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

As Tim Roberts' answer says, you should be paying interest before crediting the monthly deposit.  That will give you the required result.
However, the "expected" result (20193.81) is wrong, because interest rates are not additive like that.  In this example, the annual rate is 9.5%, i.e. a multiplier of 1.095.  To get the monthly rate we take the twelfth root of that; ¹²√1.095 = 1.00759153, i.e. a monthly rate of 0.759%, compared to 0.792% obtained by the division.
Also, it's normally wrong to store financial values in double variables.  Generally, amounts are rounded and stored to the nearest sub-unit (usually ¹/₁₀₀ or ¹/₁₀₀₀ of the unit), then the rounded value is used for subsequent computation.  Assuming we're using a currency with one hundred subdivisions, we get a final result of 18982.32 using the corrected code:
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

double balanceWithMonthlyDeposit(double initialInvestment, double monthlyDeposit,
                                 double interestRate, int numberOfYears)
{
    constexpr double currency_subunit = 0.01; // For euros, pounds, dollars, etc

    auto balance = static_cast<long>(initialInvestment / currency_subunit);
    auto const deposit = static_cast<long>(monthlyDeposit / currency_subunit);
    double monthly = std::pow(1 + interestRate/100.0,  1.0/12) - 1;

    for (int i = 0;  i < numberOfYears;  ++i) { // For each year
        long yearlyInterest = 0;
        for (int j = 0;  j < 12;  ++j) { // For each month
            long interestEarned = static_cast<long>(static_cast<double>(balance) * monthly);
            yearlyInterest += interestEarned;
            balance += interestEarned + deposit;
        }

        std::cout << "Year " << i + 1 << ": earnt "
                  << static_cast<double>(yearlyInterest) * currency_subunit << " interest; "
                  << "balance now " << static_cast<double>(balance) * currency_subunit
                  << '\n';
    }

    return static_cast<double>(balance) * currency_subunit;
}


In my experience, the monthly interest rate is found by dividing the APR (annual percentage rate) by 12, and rounding the result to 4 decimal places (or 6 decimal places, if you are storing decimals, rather than percentages). Taking the 12th root is appropriate when you are converting APY (annual percentage yield) into a monthly interest rate, but not for APR. Here is what Investopedia says: "APR is calculated by multiplying the periodic interest rate by the number of periods in a year."

More from Investopedia: APR vs. Annual Percentage Yield (APY). "Though an APR only accounts for simple interest, the annual percentage yield (APY) takes compound interest into account. As a result, a loan’s APY is higher than its APR. The higher the interest rate—and to a lesser extent, the smaller the compounding periods—the greater the difference between the APR and APY."

Ah, perhaps the asker is in the USA, where it seems a different definition is used than the one that prevails in Europe.  I had no idea the same term was used with opposite meaning over there!

The point about rounding to nearest penny/cent/etc applies to most countries, regardless of the "APR" minefield, though.

Oh! Now, I'm learning. Before today, I never knew anything but the Truth in Lending Act, which has been law of the land in the USA since 1968. Up-voting.

You wrote: Generally, amounts are rounded and stored to the nearest sub-unit. Does that mean the computation of interestEarned (above) should be changed to long interestEarned = static_cast<long>(std::round(static_cast<double>(balance) * monthly));? The change is significant. It brings the ending balance up to 18985.41.

@tbxfreeware, I see that I wrote "round to nearest" and implemented "round down".  I don't know which is correct in financial code.  I suspect it depends whether the bank is lending or borrowing, but perhaps I'm just being cynical...

It's your ordering.  You don't get to add interest on the monthly deposit.  That money won't get interest until NEXT month.  principal = principal + principal * interest + deposit.
    for (int j = 0; j < 12; ++j) { // For each month
        interestEarned = previousBalance * interest;
        yearlyInterest = yearlyInterest + interestEarned;
        previousBalance = previousBalance + monthlyDeposit + interestEarned;                                  
    }

